# Flask SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship issue

Tags: many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having an issue with my many-to-many relationship in Flask SQLAlchemy. I have a general understanding of how this works, but I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around my example.
I'm making a tennis score keeping app and I currently have two models, Player and Score and and intermediary table Match (players can challenge each other and keep track of the matches they played). The issue is that my intermediary table has three columns that point to the same column in the Player class (player id) and I cant figure out how to make the relationship column. My code so far is as follows:

```
match = db.Table("match",
    db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True),
    db.Column("player1", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("players.id")),
    db.Column("player2", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("players.id")),
    db.Column("score", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("scores.id")),
    db.Column("winner", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("players.id"))
    )

class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "players"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fullname = db.Column(db.String)
    # scores = db.relationship("Score", secondary=match)

class Score(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "scores"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    score = db.Column(db.String)
    date = db.Column(db.String)
    # players = db.relationship("Player", secondary=match)
```

I know I'm supposed to show the relationship in both the Player and Score class to the match table (the commented out part), but if I try to create it, it gives me the following error:

"AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Player.scores - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'match'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables."

If I create it without the columns 'scores' and 'players', it creates it just fine, but then I can't query the intermediary table or add rows to it. (Or if that's possible, I don't really know how)

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Overall I understand how a many-to-many relationship is supposed to work, but I just can't wrap my head around what I'm supposed to do here. *screams in confusion*

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer to my question and I'm just gonna leave it here, in case it helps someone else struggling with the same issue...
So I was trying to use a secondary table, but that's only meant to include foreign keys, however my relationship table has other data (id, score, winner...) which turns it into an Association Object based many-to-many relationship. And that one requires mapping the relationship from Parent to the Association object instead of directly onto the child.

```
 class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'association'
    left_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('left.id'), primary_key=True)
    right_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String(50))

    parent = db.relationship("Child", back_populates="children")
    child = db.relationship("Parent", back_populates="parents")


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Association", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parents = db.relationship("Association", back_populates="child")
```